# Symfony form type: pass user domain to configureOptions

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony-forms

How can I pass the current user domain to a Symfony form type?

My service looks like:

```
# src/AppBundle/Service/GenericFormService.php

    $domain = 'mydomain';

    $formBuilder = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(
        GenericOrderType::class,
        $order,
        array_merge(
            array(
                'generic_form' => $userForm,
                'validator' => $this->validator,
                'constraints' => $constraints
            ),
            $options
        )
    );
```

and I have the form type:

```
# src/AppBundle/Form/GenericOrderType.php

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'data_class' => Order::class,
                'translation_domain' => 'NEEDS_THIS_DYNAMIC',
            ]
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer after posting the question:

```
# src/AppBundle/Service/GenericFormService.php

    $domain = 'mydomain';
    $options['translation_domain'] = $domain;

    $formBuilder = $this->formFactory->createBuilder(
        GenericOrderType::class,
        $order,
        array_merge(
            array(
                'generic_form' => $userForm,
                'validator' => $this->validator,
                'constraints' => $constraints
            ),
            $options
        )
    );
```